# Why isn't line element differential form, while area element and volume element are?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Area element and volume element are differential form, but why isn't line element?

Comment: A line element is something like $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$ and I think this $ds$ is not a differential form.

Comment: Tell us your background so that we can help you. For instance, where did you learn about differential forms? Is it from some courses, lecture notes, or textbooks? And how much do you know about differential forms and differential geometry?

Comment: I'm learning differential geometry from textbooks. I know the definition of differential forms and how to integrate it over manifolds.

Comment: Which textbooks?

Comment: Be careful about the object $ds^2$. It is one single symbol. You should not treat it as the square of $ds$ ($ds$ is undefined). The line element $ds^2$ you stated is indeed not a differential form, but instead a metric tensor field. It specifies an inner product on each tangent space. As you know, inner product is symmetric, while differential forms are defined as alternating tensor field. Over the real numbers, there is no rank $2$ tensor simultaneously being symmetric and alternating other than the zero tensor. Line element is not zero tensor at any point and hence not a differential form.

Comment: I'm reading the Japanese translation of Spivak's Calculus On Manifolds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area element is a differential only in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The line element is the differential $dx$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but it needs to be modified to curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as you mention. Similarly, the area element is also not a differential for curved surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, say.

The problem you're encountering is precisely what kept the Greeks tied up with lengths of curves. Euclid has theorems about the area of a circle and volumes of cones and pyramids, but not about the perimeter of a circle! It's not that they didn't know what it was. This problem persisted until the Renaissance when Descartes famously suggested that curves cannot be rectified.